# SQL UPDATE different column names using IF/ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to create a statement that will update a table in two different ways because there are two different versions of the database table. I have written the following:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Processes' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Critical')
BEGIN
    UPDATE Processes SET Critical = 1 WHERE SystemProcessName = 'Test'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Processes SET ServiceStartEnabled = 1, Visible = 1 WHERE SystemProcessName = 'Test'
END
```

If the column "Critical" exists then update the tables "Critical" column. Otherwise, update the "ServiceStartEnabled" & "Visible" columns.

When I run the above, SQL displays the following error:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'ServiceStartEnabled'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'Visible'.

I cannot figure out why SQL is running the UPDATE statement that is contained w/in the ELSE condition when the database I am running against has the "Critical" column contained within the "Processes" table (When I run just the SELECT statement w/in the IF EXISTS a record is returned).

In case anyone is wondering my fix was to use dynamic SQL as Gareth had mentioned, so I ended up with this:

```
    DECLARE @UpdateStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 
'Processes' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Critical')
BEGIN
SET @UpdateStatement = 'UPDATE Processes SET Critical = 1 WHERE SystemProcessName = ''Test''' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    EXEC sp_executesql @UpdateStatement
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @UpdateStatement = 'UPDATE Processes SET ServiceStartEnabled = 1, Visible = 1 
WHERE SystemProcessName = ''Test''' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    EXEC sp_executesql @UpdateStatement
END
```

Comment: "Two different versions of a database table".  Something is seriously wrong with your design.

Comment: The reason why you get an error is that the whole statement is compiled at once, so at the time of compilation there is no way of know which branch of the `IF/ELSE` will be taken, so all branches are compiled. One solution is to use dynamic sql to execute your updates to defer compilation until run time, **however**, I agree with Gordon, this is a huge code smell, and if you need to be running queries like this then you have a bigger issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I used dynamic SQL and that worked. Thank you. The reason there are 2 different versions of the table is because of a software update that required the table to be altered for new features. This update statement I was creating was to be able to jump between different releases of the software.